# How can I automap an object with a JSON property to an object without a JSON property?

Tags: c#, json, automapper

What is a good way is to automap an object with some properties, one of which is a JSON string, to another object where that JSON string would be represented by properties instead of JSON.

See the source and destination classes below for an example:

`CustomJson` will look something like this for this example but could be different for other AlertTypes: `{ "AlertPrice": 500.0 }`

```
//This is the database table representation (source)
public class Alert
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string AlertType { get; set; }
    public string CustomJson { get; set; }
}

//This is the business logic model (destination)
public class UserAlert
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string AlertType { get; set; }

    //This comes from the CustomJson string in the DB
    //A different AlertType may need to map to a different object with different properties
    public decimal AlertPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Will a `ValueResolver` allow me to do this or will it only be able to map part of the object? If not, perhaps I should just have a `Custom` property which contain the custom info instead of trying to meld it into the top-level object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CreateMap<sourceobject, destobject>()
    .AfterMap((src, dest) =>
        {
            dest.AlertPrice = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json).AlertPrice;
        });
```

Comment: This example got me to where I needed. Seems to work

Answer (score 0):

```
CreateMap<sourceobject, destobject().AfterMap((src, dest) =>
            {
                dest.AlertPrice = decimal.Parse(src.AlertPrice, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            });
```

Please use above code you have use Explicity Mapping

Comment: As you can see in my example, the `src.AlertPrice` doesn't exist. It is inside the JSON string

Comment: I think I understand your example now and it might work. I will try it

Comment: You can delete this answer